# Rewrite all requests to index.php, except /static/ directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
if ($host ~ "^example.com$") {
    rewrite . /index.php last;
}
```

How can I ask nginx to serve files inside /static/ directory without rewriting the url?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you test the value of `$host`. The usual way to differentiate host names is with multiple server blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

The `try_files` directive is used to check for the existence of a static file first, then defer to a default action if it does not exist:

```
server {
    ...

    root ...;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ { ... }
}
```

Which would work for any static files (not just those in the `/static` directory). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

However, if you specifically want the `/static` directory to be handled differently, use a prefix location with the `^~` modifier:

```
location ^~ /static { }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.